# LinqToSql DeleteAllOnSubmit becomes slow from a foreach loop

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Wanted to do some SQL processing and tried the LinqToSql functionality by adding the dbml in my proj.
Its a foreach loop (around 3k entries), from where I intend to do a simple where clause and do a subsequent deleteallonsubmit on 2 tables. (records 230k and 5.4 million respectively).

As per my understanding and assumptions from working in spark deferred computing. I thought it would not make a DB call and execute "something" on the actual tables in every iteration of foreach , or in simpler words, until I call **SubmitChanges()**. What I have noticed from the SQL profiler that it is indeed going to the SQL server in every iteration and is taking around **1 second for every iteration**.

Below is the code

```
  internal static void RemoveAllDataStartingFrom()
  {
     HistoricalRefreshDateCheckerDataContext dbContext = new HistoricalRefreshDateCheckerDataContext();
     logger = (ILog)LogManager.GetLogger("HDP.allMins");
     var counter = 0;
     allMins.ToList().ForEach((v) =>
     {
        logger.Info("For each started");
        var toBeDeletedDaily = dbContext.DailyIntervalDatas.Where(x => x.Date >= v.Value && x.Id == v.Key);
        logger.Info("Daily where completed");

        dbContext.DailyIntervalDatas.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toBeDeletedDaily);
        logger.Info("Daily deleteall completed");

        var toBeDeletedFifteenMinute = dbContext.FifteenMinuteDatas.Where(x => x.Date >= v.Value && x.Id == v.Key);
        logger.Info("Fifteen Where completed");

        dbContext.FifteenMinuteDatas.DeleteAllOnSubmit(toBeDeletedFifteenMinute);
        logger.Info("Fifteen deleteall completed ");

        logger.Info("ended. counter = " + counter++);

     });
     dbContext.SubmitChanges();
  }
```

**What I intended**

I want to run this entire thing as a single batch command ( by making either 1 or 2 database calls) . I could have written a dynamic inline script and fired it on DB. But I guess I am using the LinqToSql functionality incorrectly.

Below is my log file

[image]

**EDIT**

Code for allMins

```
 internal static void FetchIndividualStartDates(DateTime startDate)
  {

     HistoricalRefreshDateCheckerDataContext refDBData = new HistoricalRefreshDateCheckerDataContext();
     var allMaxes = refDBData.DailyIntervalDatas
           .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
           .Select(
           row =>
              new
              {
                 row.Key,
                 MaxDate = row.Max(r => r.Date)
              });
     allMaxes.ToList().ForEach((a) =>
     {         
        allMins[a.Key] = Convert.ToDateTime(a.MaxDate);
     });
  }
```

Additional Profiler logs

On every DeleteAllOnSubmit below is called

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[x], [t0].[y], [t0].[z], [t0].[a], [t0].[b], [t0].[c], [t0].[e], [t0].[Date], [t0].[Id], [t0].[_ID] AS [_ID]
FROM [dbo].[FifteenMinuteData] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Date] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[Id] = @p1)',N'@p0 datetime,@p1 varchar(8000)',@p0='2020-08-10 00:00:00',@p1='1365'
```

he below is fired when SubmitChanges() is called

[image]

I have edited some information for Data security purpose

Comment: What is `allMins` and where does it come from?

Comment: @GertArnold : allMins is a Dictionary of key value pairs. Which currently has 3k+ entries. I prepared it by some trivial query. But yes, I am looping over it.

Comment: You should probably integrate that query with the queries you show here.

Comment: @GertArnold : Code added.

Comment: If `Date` in `DailyIntervalDatas` would have been a `DateTime` you could have combined the queries. Now you can't. But with such amounts of data you shouldn't use LinqToSql anyway. This is stored-procedure stuff.

Comment: @GertArnold: ahh I felt I was applying this in wrong place. But how hard could it be for linq2sql to make it lazy or superdefer ?... Anyway, could you please tell me if I could use bulkDelete along with future actions from here : https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219736/discussion-between-ankur-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: As with *any* ORM (also Entity Framework) objects are pulled into memory, modified or marked for delete and then saved back to the database individually. Which is exactly what happens in each iteration. No way to change this ingrained behavior. That's why you shouldn't use an ORM for bulk database actions. These third-party libraries are mere palliatives and all have their own issues. My motto: do it right or else don't do it. I.e. stored procedure. That's all I'm going to say about this.

Comment: @GertArnold : ok. If youre being that critical of it, I have no issues in using stored procs. I was just on exploration journey and wanted to use linqsql in one of my new projects.
Sorry for being a drag.. you sure nothing apart from SP are worth exploring in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Your log doesn't indicate where the actual SQL executions are occuring only that the specified lines are being executed. For the SQL executions, you'll need to do something like `dbContext.Log = Console.Out`.

With Linq to SQL, the Unit of Work pattern with SubmitChanges waits queues up the statements, but does issue separate queries to the database for each record. It doesn't batch up the statements into a single database request. For that you will need a third-party extension or move up to something like EF Core which does support batching.

Better yet, for bulk operations, you may want to consider using a stored proc or custom SQL for deletes and SqlBulkCopy for inserts. LINQ is great for loading objects, manipulating objects in memory and saving them back, but isn't ideal for bulk operations like `DELETE FROM table WHERE parentId = @ParentId`.

EDIT: Based on the additional information, you are not seeing delete staements being issued when calling DeleteAllOnSubmit, but rather select statements caused by passing the queryables of toBeDeletedDaily and toBeDeletedFifteenMinute which are executed inside of the DeleteAllOnSubmit when adding the list of items to be deleted. Instead of looping through the allmins, consider how you could join the allMins with the delete operation and possibly remove the forEach iterations to wrap the selects into a single pass. Consider how you would create a single DELETE FROM  statement including the logic of All Mins in the where/join clauses natively in SQL and that might help guide you to solving for that part of the problem.

Comment: I am checking this : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore/ . Please let me know if I am looking in the right palce